# Origin not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin Perl

Tags: perl, cors

I am making a request to remote perl server. but got the problem as

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://otherdomain.com/getPub.pl?content=hello. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I already enable access_control_allow_origin to be "*" in perl script, codes as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use warnings;

my $cgi = new CGI;

print $cgi -> header(
-type => 'text/plain',
-access_control_allow_origin => '*',
  );
my $content = $cgi -> param('content');
open(CON,">content.txt") || die "can't open $!";
print CON $content;
close(CON);
```

and the js request as followings:

```
function sendData(){
    var url = "http://otherdomain.com/getPub.pl?content=hello";
    var xhr = createCORSRequest("GET", url);
    if(!xhr){
        throw new Error ('CORS not supported');
        }
    xhr.send();

}
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     if("withCredentials" in xhr){
       xhr.open(method,url,true);
     }else if(typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    }else{
            xhr = null;
    }
return xhr;
}
```

the response header as:

```
Allow:GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 07 Jan 2013 16:55:44 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
```

What is the matter?

Comment: Look at the Net tab in your browser's developer tools. Check which requests are being made. Are the responses what you expect? Do you see an unexpected OPTIONS request? (It is possible you are getting tripped up by preflight checks).

Comment: Check out if Perl really returns the header you want by checking full headers in browser's console or tool like `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: hi @Quentin , it really due to the OPTIONS request. I have no idea how to respond it in perl.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: @Quentin hi, it finally works using PHP as I written below. I really have no idea about the reason.

Answer (score 4):

It finally works in PHP, although I still didn't see the difference.
Summary as :

1.
When using perl as:

```
my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi -> header(
-type => 'text/plain',
-access_control_allow_origin => '*',
-access_control_allow_headers => 'content-type,X-Requested-With',
-access_control_allow_methods => 'GET,POST,OPTIONS',
-access_control_allow_credentials => 'true',
);
```

The HTTP headers as:

Request header:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:example.org
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/testCORS.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
```

Response header:

```
Allow:GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 08 Jan 2013 05:52:26 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
```

2.
BUT in PHP, it works!!!: I didn't see the differences!

code as:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,");
 #header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
 ?>
```

Response header :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 08 Jan 2013 05:52:10 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your server is responding to an OPTIONS request to that URL with the proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. The browser will "preflight" your request by first making an OPTIONS request. If that fails, it will not try your request at all.

Comment: Hi Charles, yes, it request OPTIONS. But, I have no idea how to respond to an OPTIONS request. Thanks

Comment: Respond the same as to other requests, but only with headers, no body. You should be able to configure your web server to run a Perl script when it gets such a request. The script itself doesn't need to do much of anything except set headers.

Comment: The response to an OPTIONS request should include Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials headers, too. A CGI script to handle just OPTIONS requests would just have a few print statements, wouldn't even need to use any Perl modules. So you could start your script with something like `if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq 'OPTIONS') { print the three header lines and a blank line } else { do regular script for GET method }`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I still could not found the error in perl. However it works in PHP as I written below.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it on apache using .htaccess file
put it in the same directory as your perl file
This solved the problem for me.
e.g

```
<Files "getPub.pl">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
</Files>
```